# Charged particle near a loop of varying current

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, classical-electrodynamics

Consider a loop of radius $R=1$ centered at the origin lies on the $x-y$ plane, carrying an electric current $I$. A point particle of charge $q$ is located initially at $(0,0,z)$ and at rest. The signs of $q$ and $I$ are the same.

Now we let the current to change $I=I(t)$ (it either decreases or increases monotonically).

My questions are:

1. What will be the influence of the changing current on the particle?
2. Will the particle have a counter action on the loop?
3. Does it matter in the particle has an initial velocity $\vec{v}=v_0\hat{z},\;v_0\neq 0$?

We know that along the $z$ axis the loop has a magnetic field $$\vec{B}=\frac{\mu_0}{2}\frac{I}{(z^2+1)^{3/2}}\hat{z} \tag 1 $$

So as far as I can tell, since eq. $1$ points along the $z$ axis, it will not affect the particle at all, even if the particle is moving ($\vec{v}\times\vec{B}=0$). So any effects are due to the changing current.

Changing the current and thus changing the magnetic field and it's flux, will cause by Faraday's law a counter action on the electric field along the loop, but again not affecting the particle.

By ampere's law, the moving particle (if it moves) will cause a tangent magnetic field along the loop, but being tangent it will not affect the charges on the loop (they move in the same direction).

This question was given to me as riddle, so I assume I'm missing something in my analysis. In particular, I was implied the existence of a paradox that unless solved would make the system to appear to act as a recoilless gun.

So intuitively I believe the changing current on the loop accelerates the particle along the $z$ axis, while the accelerating particle induces some force on the loop that accelerates it to the other way and/or changes the current the other way(if the current was made to increase, to accelerating particle decreases it)

Comment: Shouldn't it be like,  $$B=\frac{\mu_0 Ir^2}{2\sqrt{(z^2+r^2)^3}}$$ ?

Comment: @NehalSamee For simplicity I've set $r=1$.

Comment: The denominator should have a $2$ ?